# how can I prevent custom navigation bar stretch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

In my app I make a `viewcontroller` that  contain `imageview` and custom navigation bar and connect `navigationbaritem` and `navigationbar` outlets to code .

I define `UINavigationBar` and `UINavigationItem` as outlet.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navigationBar;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *barItem1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@end
```

When image don't load every thing  okay but when I fetch image  and load view height of navigation bar changed. How can I prevent to stretch navigation bar?

i use  xcode 7.3 and  ios 9.X.

i define

image description :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qADgp.png)

Comment: remove all this. and hide nav bar. and simple create one uiview and set left button, right button and label in middle.. or you can also add uiimageview inside uiview and set image as per your requirement. good luck brohh

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent your bar from stretching by hardcoding the height value of your bar element in the storyboard.
To do this you need to set the height constraint of your element.